# get xpath from xsl variable

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am trying to get some xpath from xsl variable using xsl ver 1.0 .
That’s  my variable:

```
  <xsl:variable name ="myVar">
        <RefData RefTag="test1" bbb="false" />
        <RefData RefTag="test2" bbb="false" />
        <RefData RefTag="test3" bbb="false" />
        <RefData RefTag="test4" bbb="true"  />
        <RefData RefTag="test5" bbb="false" />
        <RefData RefTag="test6" bbb="false" />
  </xsl:variable>
```

I am trying to get bbb attribure value using the RefTag value:

```
<xsl:if test="$myVar/RefData[@RefTag = 'test3']/@bbb">
```

this is not working.

VS XSL Debugger returns an error:
"To use a result tree fragment in a path expression, first convert it to a node-set using the msxsl:node-set() function."

I don't understand how to use msxsl:node-set() function, and anyway I prefer not to use msxsl namesapce.

Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**One solution that doesn't need the xxx:node-set() extension** is the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <!--                                           -->
    <xsl:variable name ="myVar">
        <RefData RefTag="test1" bbb="false" />
        <RefData RefTag="test2" bbb="false" />
        <RefData RefTag="test3" bbb="false" />
        <RefData RefTag="test4" bbb="true"  />
        <RefData RefTag="test5" bbb="false" />
        <RefData RefTag="test6" bbb="false" />
    </xsl:variable>
 <!--                                           -->
    <xsl:variable name="vrefVar" select=
     "document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='myVar']"
     />
 <!--                                           -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="$vrefVar/*[@RefTag='test3']/@bbb"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When the above transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted result is produced**:

`false`

**Do note the use of the XSLT [`document()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-document) function** in order to access the required `<xsl:variable>` simply as an element in an xml document.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:variable name="myVariable" select="msxsl:node-set($myVar)"/>
```

You can avoid msxsl namespace by moving variable contents to the source xml.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming this XML:

```
<test1>
  <RefData RefTag="test1"/>
  <RefData RefTag="test2"/>
  <RefData RefTag="test3"/>
  <RefData RefTag="test4"/>
  <RefData RefTag="test5"/>
  <RefData RefTag="test6"/>
</test1>
```

Something like this could work:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="test1/RefData"/>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="RefData">
    <xsl:variable name="myVar">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@RefTag = 'test1'">false</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@RefTag = 'test2'">false</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@RefTag = 'test3'">false</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@RefTag = 'test4'">true</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@RefTag = 'test5'">false</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@RefTag = 'test6'">false</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>true</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!--<text x="{$myVar}"/>-->
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I think that you didn't understand the question. this data is not in the input xml so I can't assume the xml abouve.
I need to use xsl:variable